# Getting the matched word exactly

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, ksh

I have looked through a number of question but they do not satisfactorily reply to my question.

I need to print words that match the pattern exactly not the lines containing that word.
For example:

> I am going home.
>   Home is where heart is.

So when I search with pattern "home", I should get

> home Home

**I understand that** `grep -o` **will make my task easier, but** **my** `grep` **does not support that option. So I need some other solution.**

Also I need an exact match. So that if there is a word `homeless` it should not be picked in selection.

Answer (score 2):

Playing with `perl` :

```
$ echo 'I am going home. Home is where heart is.' | 
    perl -lne 'for (split /\W+/) {print $& if /\bhome\b/i}'
```

And even shorter, adapted from [Joseph R.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26909/joseph-r) comment bellow (thanks to him)

```
$ echo 'I am going home. Home is where heart is.' | 
    perl -lne 'print $& while /\bhome\b/ig'
```

Result:

```
home
Home
```

Comment: Even easier: `perl -lne 'print $1 while /\b(home)\b/ig'`

Comment: Even shorter, see my edited post ;)

Comment: That's why I like Perl that much, concision is great with this programming language !

Comment: not working for this `I am going home. home,shelter,home is where heart is.` output is only 2 home

Comment: Concision? `tr | grep` is shorter! @Hackaholic Use `\W+` instead of `\s+` as the word separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tr.html) to normalize word separators, then [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) to print matching words (with the options `-Fx` to match a string exactly and `-i` for case insensitivity).

```
tr -cs A-Za-z \\n | grep -Fxi home
```

If you're in a non-ASCII locale, note that many implementations of `tr` operate on bytes, not characters. Use another tool such as sed to perform the word separator normalization.

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*/\n/g' | grep -Fxi home
```

All the commands in this answer are POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

using `awk`:

```
echo "I am going home. Home is where heart is. I dont like Homework." | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/,"",$i); if(match(tolower($i),/^(home)$/))print $i;}}'
```

output:

```
home.
Home
```

Comment: I think you used home or Home for pattern matching. I want to use just home and still get the desired output.

Comment: yep you need something else??

Comment: now check the code. i have edited for what you wanted

Comment: This option is also picking the words which have "home" inside it like "homeless" or "homework"

Comment: @haldar55 edited the code as per your requirement

Comment: What if there is something like `Food,Home,Shelter` Will it give me just `Home` out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to look for whole words similar to `grep -o -w`:

```
$ echo "I am going home. Home is where heart is." | awk -v 'RS=[^[:alnum:]_]' -v w="home" 'tolower($0)==w'
home
Home
```

As Gilles points out, this requires an `awk`, such as GNU `awk`, which supports regular expressions for `RS`.

Comment: That's good, except that support for `RS` being a regular expression is not a standard feature. A system where the shell is ksh and `grep` isn't GNU or BSD grep is likely to have an awk that doesn't go much beyond POSIX.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf %s\\n 'I am going home. Home is where the heart is.' | 
sed 's/\([hH]ome\)*.\{,1\}/\1/g'
```

#### OUTPUT

homeHome

Comment: he want to search for home and Home only using `home`. in your code you have added capital `H`

Comment: But that's not the question - he says he wants to *match* a *pattern*. `home` is a pattern with one possible *match* - which is `home`. In other words, it is an instance.

Comment: My mistake, in case I wasn't clear, I wanted "home" to be matched to any way the word "Home" comes into picture i.e the checking should be case insensitive.

Comment: @haldar55 - in that case you need to filter the pattern first, at least you do with any portable `sed` statement. `tr` makes an excellent filter for that. Or even `sed` - but `tr` is faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over words, grep the specified word and remove punctuation characters

```
$ s="I am going home. Home is where heart is." 
$ for w in $s; do echo $w; done | grep -Ei '(^|[[:punct:]]*)home([[:punct:]]*|$)' | tr -d '[[:punct:]]'
home
Home
```

Comment: Why not use `[^[:alpha:]]` for “not a letter”? That's what it's for. You should disable globbing in case there are characters `\[?*` in the string. And since punctuation is supposed to separate words, you would need to put all punctuation characters in `IFS`.